# Update when null insert when does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple records have the same ID but different values. I want copy records from other table to this table. I want to update if record is null to the minimum position, or insert into the next position if the value does not exist.

Here is my Target table:

**ID | Position | Value**

1  | 1        | A

2  | 1        | B

2  | 2        | null

2  | 3        | null

2  | 4        | C

3  | 1        | A

4  | 1        | D

4  | 2        | B

Source table:

**ID | Value**

1  | C

2  | N

3  | B

4  | D

5  | A

6  | null

7  | B

Wanted result table:

**ID | Position | Value**

1  | 1        | A

1  | 2        | C

2  | 1        | B

2  | 2        | N

2  | 3        | null

2  | 4        | C

3  | 1        | A

3  | 2        | B

4  | 1        | D

4  | 2        | B

5  | 1        | A

7  | 1        | B

My query is:

MERGE Target AS T

USING (SELECT S.ID, MAX(E.POS) AS PosMax, MIN(E.POS) as PosMin, S.Value

FROM Source S

LEFT OUTER JOIN Target E ON S.ID = E.ID

WHERE S.Value IS NOT NULL AND E.Value IS NULL

GROUP BY S.ID, S.Value) AS SC

ON T.ID = SC.ID

WHEN MATCHED AND SC.Value IS NOT NULL AND EG.Value IS NULL AND T.POS = SC.PosMin

THEN

UPDATE SET

EG.Value = SC.Value

WHEN NOT MATCHED AND SC.Value IS NOT NULL

THEN

INSERT (ID, Position, Value)

VALUES (SC.D, ISNULL(SC.PosMax, 0) + 1, SC.Value);

This only updates the null value with the minimum position and insert the value if there is not exist ID. If the ID existed. It will not insert because the Match T.ID = SC.ID.

Example of ID 3, It does not inser value B in position 2.

Does anyone have different approach or strategy? Or I have to write a second query to insert if the ID is the same and value not.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a `MERGE` statement.

Comment: The closest things MySQL has are [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) (which does a DELETE followed by an INSERT) and [INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: I took the question off the MYSQL thread

Answer (score 0):

I think your ON needs the position as well.
ON T.ID = SC.ID and T.pos=SC.minpos.

And the subquery to build SC should be an inner join. You don't want records if you don't have matching values in target.

Comment: I want to insert the ID which does not exist in to the target table. ID 5 and ID 6 for example. If I only use inner join, it will not insert the ID 5 and 6.

Comment: That's what the INSERT part of the MERGE is for. The search condition finds the record you want to update, if it fails you INSERT.

Comment: First of all, the merge will not include the values with same IDs if I try inner join.
CREATE TABLE TargetA (
[ID] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
[POS] INT NOT NULL,
[VALUE] varchar(10) NULL)

CREATE TABLE SourceA (
[ID] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
[VALUE] varchar(10) NULL)


INSERT INTO [dbo].SourceA (
[ID],
VALUE)
VALUES
('1','C')
,('2','N')
,('3','B')
,('4','D')
,('5','A')
,('6','null')
,('7','B')

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].TargetA (
[ID],
POS,
VALUE)
VALUES
('1',1,'A')
,('2',1,'B')
,('2',2,'null')
,('2',3,'null')
,('2',4,'C')
,('3',1,'A')
,('4',1,'D')
,('4',2,'B')

Comment: MERGE TargetA AS T
USING (SELECT S.ID, MAX(E.POS) AS PosMax, MIN(E.POS) as PosMin, S.Value
FROM SourceA S
LEFT OUTER JOIN TargetA E ON S.ID = E.ID
WHERE S.Value IS NOT NULL AND E.Value IS NULL
GROUP BY S.ID, S.Value) AS SC
ON T.ID = SC.ID
WHEN MATCHED AND SC.Value IS NOT NULL AND T.Value IS NULL AND T.POS = SC.PosMin
THEN
UPDATE SET
T.Value = SC.Value
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND SC.Value IS NOT NULL
THEN
INSERT (ID, POS, Value)
VALUES (SC.ID, ISNULL(SC.PosMax, 0) + 1, SC.Value);

Comment: if I use left outer join, it will not insert these 2 values ,('2','N')
,('3','B') from target table.